# Verb + '-ly' = adjectvie?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes

I am learning in Korea. So I rarely have an opportunity of real English.

Anyway, My Teacher said that 'noun + -ly = adjective' and 'adjective + -ly = adverbs'

Then, what about 'verb + -ly'? Is it possible?

somepeople said that is possible and 'verb + -ly' will become adjectives or adverbs.

but other people also said that is impossible.

I really want to know that.

Verb + ly = possible? or impossible?

If that is possible, What meaning they have?

Comment: Do you have an example of a verb that takes the ly suffix?  I can only think of those that do not: *walkly, *speakly, *drinkly, etc.  (In other words, it is not possible.)

Comment: Maybe the people you were talking to had in mind words like _sound_ and _sight_ that can be nouns or verbs, so that when you get a legitimate word like _soundly_ or _sightly_, the people you were talking wanted to credit to the verb form as the basis of the modifier. But this view is based on a misunderstanding of what is going on, as phoog points out. (In fact, in my examples, _sightly_ is an adjective built on the noun _sight_; but _soundly_ is an adverb built on the adjective _sound_, which is identical in appearance to both the noun _sound_ and the verb _sound_.)

Comment: It is better to have a grammar. People often have funny ideas about the system of their language and what people say spontaneously is often imprecise, if not completely wrong. In grammars you find better explanations. And you find examples. Making up examples of one's own is no efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past or present participle of many verbs may act as an adjective; such an adjective may take the *-ly* suffix to be employed as an adverb.

> Prof. Sartorius' lectures interest me. They are so interesting. He speaks interestingly.
>
> Grichuk's voice broke. He spoke in a broken voice. He spoke brokenly.

But creating new words this way is dangerous—it doesn't always work. Adjective + -ly is usually OK, but not the others. Understand these constructions when you read them, but don't try to use them as patterns for new words without a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is really helpful for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few examples of adding -ly to a verb and getting an adjective (comely, maybe shapely), adding -ly to a noun and getting an adjective (portly), or adding -ly to an adjective and getting another adjective (sickly), but I don't think there's a rule behind it, and I certainly wouldn't stick -ly onto verbs haphazardly and expect an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited and relative short list of adjectives with -ly as in

- stately, elderly, deadly, otherwordly, friendly, brotherly

-ly was originaly a suffix that formed adjectives from nouns and other word classes. This suffix is connected with the adjective like.

Today -ly is used as suffix for adverbs of manner.

It is no use forming new adjectives with -ly on your own. Most of these forms are in the dictionary and you can't use this kind of word formation freely. And you can't add -ly to other word classes.